# Is there a way to import multiple files in PowerBI while keeping each file as an individual data table?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

How to expand each Binary/Table to a individual table? If I loaded lots of tables as shown below, how should I expand each Table as an individual data table? Without going thur each row and right click to add as a new query?  Or should I do when importing data? It always combines all files from a folder location. How to import all files, but keep each file as an individual data table? Thanks for your help in advance:)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WlN3.png)

If I loaded lots of tables as shown below, how should I expand each Table as an individual data table? Without going thur each row and right click to add as a new query?  Or should I do when importing data? It always combines all files from a folder location. How to import all files, but keep each file as an individual data table? Thanks for your help in advance:)

Comment: Following the same question, in each table, assuming the project number is in Cell C7, Can I add a column to each table that the contains Cell C7 value in each row?